# Where does this command put the apk for react native?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I have followed the instructions from here [react-native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) to generate a release apk. I have run the command

> gradlew assembleRelease

according to the docs and it says that a release.apk should be located here

> android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk

Althought the build succeeds I do not see it there. The only thing that I see generated is

> android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk

Despite the fact that I have configured the global gradle.properties file which maps to the keystore... Not only do I get this. But the apk doesnt work anyway when I drag it on to the android emulator. But if I open android studio to the android project and press the green button, then the app does deploy correctly, and the app runs as expected in the android studio emulator.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You also need to edit build.gradle file as documented in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: Thanks ill accept soon ... I did that but missed the line signingConfig signingConfigs.release